# Lambda expression Contain () method does not work in Advantage Database 9?

Tags: lambda, advantage-database-server

I am using Sybase Advantage Database 9.1

and I try to use Lambda expression Contain method to retrieve data ,but it does not work.

```
var order = order.Where(x => x.name == "James");
```

it return 10 rows data.

but If I change to

```
var order = order.Where(x => x.name.Contains("James"));
```

it return 0.

x.name is string field.

anybody know why it happened?

How should I do to use Contain method?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that support for the canonical function `Contains` was added with changes for Entity Framework v4.  That was in Advantage v10.x.  Those changes were not merged back into the v9.x branch.

Comment: Do you know what can I use instead of Contains()?